# Twitter OAuth dynamic Callback URL

Tags: twitter, oauth, callback

how can I make the callback url dynamic? With different hostnames for the same domain.
I use Abrahams twitteroauth https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth.

On the `getRequestToken($callbackUrl)` function I can set a callback url but this doesn't matter.

Br

Comment: Passing a complete URL as a string to `getRequestToken` should work. I'll look into it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the 'callback' url dynamic. But 'izeed' came up with a pretty decent solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10573287/1580615