# Dynamic callback url support in Twitter - Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, omniauth

I am using omniauth-twitter gem for user authentication in my rails app.

I am trying to implement dynamic callback by passing the callback_url as the paramater

```
/auth/twitter?oauth_callback=http://mynewwebsite.com
```

But twitter redirects to the callback_url specified in the twitter application settings. Am i missing anything here?

Is dynamic callback not supported by twitter? any other gem to implement this feature? Kindly help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no dynamic callback.

You could make a dispatcher: place the intended callback URL in a cookie, send the user to Twitter, get him back and then redirect him where his cookie tells you to.

Comment: Thanks @izeed. Had thought of it if there is no dynamic callback

Answer (score 0):

You could use url query to send any additional params. So it can be used instead of cookies. For example

```
#url
"/auth/twitter?x_auth_access_type=read&target=customer_login"

#controller
def twitter
  if params[:target] == "customer_login"
    ...
  end
end
```

or use smth like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888263/setting-up-rails-routes-based-on-querystring) to create routes based on QueryString